# Regex in Axios mock api adapter don't work

Tags: javascript, regex, mocking, axios

I'm testing my Vue application with [Axios](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter).
The problem is that some regex seems not to work...

For example: I need to return two different responses for those two apis:

`/api/sources`

and

`/api/sources/123123123`

So I wrote two different adaptors:

```
mock.onGet(/dmd\.mocked\/api\/sources\/([A-Za-z]|[0-9]|-)+$/).reply(() => {
  return [200, ResponseObject.getSpecificSourceInQueue];
});

mock.onGet(/dmd\.mocked\/api\/sources/).reply((config) => {
  return [200, ResponseObject.queuedFilesList];
});
```

The problem is that even when calling the api with the id in the url, the adpater triggered is always the last one and not the first one with the regex to catch the source id.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `/dmd\.mocked\/api\/sources$/` as the second one. And `/dmd\.mocked\/api\/sources\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$/` as the first one.

Comment: Yes, the first group looks wrong: `([A-Za-z]|[0-9]|-)+` matches strings like AAAAaaab, 213567865, ---------

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, that worked!